# charts.PerformanceSummary() not working for intraday data

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to plot intraday data using `PerformanceAnalytics::charts.PerformanceSummary()`

but I get the following error message:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(e[,1:10])

Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(.POSIXct(.index(x)), tz = indexTZ(x)) : 
      invalid 'tz' value
```

It seems that `charts.PerformanceSummary` only takes daily data but not intraday?

Can someone please come up with a solution for this?

```
 e <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000369303493611195, 0, 
0, 0.000590667454223315, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000150829562594268, 
0.000150806816467952, -0.00015078407720126, -0.000150806816468174, 
0.000301659125188536, 0, 0, -0.000617817867292869, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.000107944732297138, 0.000323799244468459, -0.000215796288303927, 
0, 0.000215842866393423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = c("America/New_York", "EST", "EDT"), tzone = c("America/New_York", 
"EST", "EDT"), index = structure(c(1496755860, 1496755920, 1496755980, 
1496756040, 1496756100, 1496756160), tzone = c("America/New_York", 
"EST", "EDT"), tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AADR", "AAXJ", "ACIM", "ACSI", 
"ACTX", "ACWF", "ACWI", "ACWV", "ACWX", "ADRA")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `POSIXlt` index. You should convert it to `POSIXct`, which is most easily accomplished by creating a new xts object. Try the commands below.

```
e <- xts(coredata(e), as.POSIXct(index(e)))
PerformanceAnalytics::charts.PerformanceSummary(e[,1:10])
```

The chart throws an error with your example data, after drawing the first plot:

```
Error in segments(xlim[1], y_grid_lines(ylim), xlim[2], y_grid_lines(ylim),  : 
  cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates
```

But that may be because there aren't enough observations. Let me know if it doesn't work on your actual data and I'll investigate further.